# Regex for splitting a string delimited by | when not enclosed on double quotes

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to count the number of columns in a pipe delimited string in java.
   The column data will always be enclosed by double quotes or it will be empty.

eg:

```
"1234"|"Name"||"Some description with ||| in it"|"Last Column"
```

The above should be counted as 5 columns including one empty column after "Name" column.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to count only, or do you want to extract the data also?

Comment: I just need the count of columns.

Comment: you can split using `\"\|` and get the array length

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley, that doesn't work for an input as simple as "||". That should be 3 columns, your solution gives 1.

Comment: @aioobe: yea. if the input has single empty pipe then this will work `input.split("\"\\||\\|\"").length`

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley, nope. You're [still wrong](http://ideone.com/k7IsF).

Comment: @aioobe: i just mean [two](http://ideone.com/Rqlv9) consecutive pipes with double quotes around it.if it is three or more then we need to replace similar to what you did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
String input =
    "\"1234\"|\"Name\"||\"Some description with ||| in it\"|\"Last Column\"";
//  \_______/ \______/\/\_________________________________/ \_____________/    
//      1        2    3                 4                          5

int cols = input.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"", "")  // remove "..."
                .replaceAll("[^|]", "")        // remove anything else than |
                .length() + 1;                 // Count the remaining |, add 1

System.out.println(cols);   // 5
```

IMO it's not very robust though. I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions if you plan on handling escaped quotes, for instance.

Comment: You beat me to it. Also point out that escaped quote can be a problem. +1

Comment: I did that in the last line :-)

Comment: Nice way to solve it. It can be made to handle escapes just fine tho (see my answer). ;-)

Comment: You could of course also just replace `\"` with nothing before solving it.

Comment: @aioobe, nope, `"foo"|"bar\\"|"baz"`.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly improved the expressions in [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977004/107152):

```
int cols = input.replaceAll("\"(?:[^\"\\]+|\\.)*\"|[^|]+", "")
                .length() + 1;
```

Handles escapes in quotes, and uses a single expression to remove everything except the delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex I used a while back that also deals with escaped quotes **AND escaped delimiters**. It's probably overkill for your requirements (counting columns) but perhaps it'll help you or someone else in the future with their parsing.

```
(?<=^|(?<!\\)\|)(\".*?(?<=[^\\])\"|.*?(?<!\\(?=\|))(?=")?|)(?=\||$)

and broken down as:
(?<=^|(?<!\\)\|)             // look behind to make sure the token starts with the start anchor (first token) or a delimiter (but not an escaped delimiter)
(                            // start of capture group 1
  \".*?(?<=[^\\])\"          //   a token bounded by quotes
  |                          //   OR
  .*?(?<!\\(?=\|))(?=")?     //   a token not bounded by quotes, any characters up to the delimiter (unless escaped)
  |                          //   OR
                             //   empty token
)                            // end of capture group 1
(?=\||$)                     // look ahead to make sure the token is followed by either a delimiter or the end anchor (last token)

when you actually use it it'll have to be escaped as:
(?<=^|(?<!\\\\)\\|)(\\\".*?(?<=[^\\\\])\\\"|.*?(?<!\\\\(?=\\|))(?=\")?|)(?=\\||$)
```

It's complicated, but there's method to this madness: Other regular expressions I googled would fall over if either a column at the start or end of the line was empty, delimited quotes were in odd places, the line or column started or ended with an escaped delimiter, and a bunch of other edge-case scenarios.

The fact that you're using a pipe as a delimiter makes this regex even more difficult to read/understand. A tip is where you see a pipe by itself "|", it's a conditional OR in regex, and when it's escaped "\|", it's your delimiter.